# MFTF Adobe Commerce Supplied faild

Tags: plugin

I'm trying to pubish a new plugin for magento 2.4. When I upload the plugin to the magento marketplace the "MFTF Adobe Commerce Supplied" review fails. I got this message:

```
AdminCreateAndEditConfigurableProductSettingsTest : Broken
AdminCreateAndEditBundleProductSettingsTest : Broken
AdminCreateCategoryTest : Passed
AdminConfigurableProductCreateTest : Broken
AdminCreateSimpleProductTest : Failed
AdminCreateOrderWithSimpleProductTest : Broken
AdminCreateCreditMemoPartialRefundTest : Passed
CreateInvoiceWithShipmentAndCheckInvoicedOrderTest : Broken
CreateInvoiceWithZeroSubtotalCheckoutTest : Passed
MoveConfigurableProductsInComparedOnOrderPageTest : Passed
StorefrontClearAllCompareProductsTest : Passed
StorefrontUpdateWishlistTest : Passed
StorefrontReorderAsGuestTest : Passed
AddConfigurableProductToOrderFromShoppingCartTest : Passed
StorefrontCustomerCheckoutTest : Passed
AdminCreateCustomerWithCountryUSATest : Passed
AdminCreateNewCustomerOnStorefrontTest : Passed
StorefrontGuestCheckoutTest : Passed
```

do you have any idea how can I solve this problem. Thanks a lot